# ReactJS hide first child of map function

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I am building a BlackJack game  and I am mapping over a dealer cards array to display the dealer cards. I want to hide the first card that is returned from the array.

This is my DealerCards component.

```
import React from 'react'

const DealerCards = props => {
  return (
    <div className="text-center">
      Dealer Cards
      <div className="text-center m-auto flex justify-center">
        {props.dealerCards.length > 0 ? (
          <div className="mx-auto flex justify-center">
            {props.dealerCards.map(card => (
              <div key={card[0].code}>
                <img
                  className="m-5 h-40 dealer-cards"
                  src={card[0].image}
                  alt={card[0].code}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ) : (
          <div></div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default DealerCards
```

And this is the CSS I am using to try and hide it.

```css
.dealer-cards:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

I also tried moving the `dealer-cards` className to the images parent div but got the same result.
What am I doing wrong??
Let me know if you need to see more of the code.

Comment: `first-of-type` only works on tags, like `div`, `p`, etc.

Comment: You're right, thank you.  My approach was off....any ideas how I should approach this then?

Comment: If you don't need the first card in the DOM, you could skip it. `dealerCards.slice(1).map(...)`

Comment: Try the `first-child` or `nth-child` selectors.

Comment: So I found the answer in a separate post [CSS selector for first element with class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)...

Answer (score 1):

dealerCards.slice(1).map(...) will hide the first child.

Answer (score 1):

You can update existing CSS style to like this,

```
.dealer-cards:nth-child(1) { display: none; }
```

I think this may help you.